# Trocar as letras do início de um email por outro caractere

Tags: php, regex, email, preg-replace

Estou tentando substituir letras por asteríscos de um email usando o `preg_replace()` do php, mas o php pega todas as letras do email, porém eu só quero colocar os asteríscos nas primeiras letras.
exemplo:

entrada: emailteste2020@gmail.com
saida:  *********2020@gmail.com

Mas meu código está pegando todas as letras e substituindo por asteríscos
exemplo:
entrada: emailteste2020@gmail.com
saida:  `*********2020@*****.***`

meu código:

```
<?php 
    $email="emailteste16@gmail.com";

    $emailRegex=preg_replace('/([a-z])/','*', $email);
    
    echo $email;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $emailRegex;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa de regex, basta ir percorrendo a string e trocando as letras por asteriscos. Quando encontrar algo que não é letra, pare:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($email); $i++) {
    if (ctype_lower($email[$i]))
        $email[$i] = '*';
    else break;
}
echo $email;
```

Usei [`ctype_lower`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-lower.php) que verifica se é letra minúscula. Se for, troco por asterisco, e se não for eu interrompo o loop.

---

Mas se quiser muito usar regex:

```
function troca($m) {
  return str_repeat('*', strlen($m[1])). $m[2];
}
$email="emailteste16@gmail.com";
$emailRegex=preg_replace_callback('/^([a-z]+)(\d*@.+)$/', 'troca', $email);
    
echo $emailRegex;
```

Eu crio 2 grupos de captura ([indicado pelos parênteses](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)): um com as letras do início e outro contendo dos números em diante. Eu uso `\d*` para indicar [zero ou mais](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) dígitos (para o caso de não ter nenhum), depois a `@`, e `.+` (um ou mais caracteres) para ir até o final da string. Também uso os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que indicam respectivamente o início e fim da string.

Então eu crio uma função de substituição, que pega o primeiro grupo, verifica o tamanho e gera uma outra string do mesmo tamanho, mas contendo só asteriscos - é o que [`str_repeat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) faz. Em seguida eu concateno com o segundo grupo, que contém o restante da string.

A diferença é que para usar a função eu devo usar [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback) em vez de `preg_replace`.

Particularmente eu prefiro a primeira opção. Regex até funciona mas me parece desnecessariamente complicado para o seu caso.

Lembrando que nenhuma solução valida se a string é de fato um email.